# R. Add custom marks at specific values inside histogram

Tags: r, label, histogram

I made a histogram using R (please see picture attached). This is the code:

```
hist(df$A, 
     border = rgb(1,0,0,0.8),
     main = "",
     breaks = 1000,
     las = 1,
     mgp = c(3, 0.6, 0),
     cex.axis = 1,
     xlim=c(-0.6,0.6))
```

I would like to add a small vertical tick at a some specific values (e.g. 0.5704, 0.5455,0.5555) of df$A along the x axis but inside the histogram, over the red line, in order to label these positions afterwards with specific names (e.g. "a","b","c"). I know how to add the names using mtext(), but I don't know how to add these specific marks. Any suggestion is welcomed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrows()` with `code = 0` to draw short line segments. You can customize how tall they are by setting their end point via the `y1` argument, and you can also change their color and so forth.

```
x_marks <- c(0.5704, 0.5455,0.5555)
tickmark_height <- 500
arrows(x0 = x_marks, x1 = x_marks,
       y0 = rep(0, length(x_marks)), y1 = rep(tickmark_height, length(x_marks)),
       code = 0)
```

Comment: Excellent @MHammer !